aws resource explorer, show only resources I've created
In azure on the home page I would see only the resources that I've personally created.
In AWS I've turned on Resource Explorer, and it is showing a list of more than 350 resources in multiple regions
I've only used EC2 in us-east-1
I presume this is all default stuff created with the account.
Is there a way to show only the resources I've personally created ?
